# Prism 6 Add Authentication LoginWindow and Mainwindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, prism-6

I have created WPF C# Project with Prism 6,

and my Project Based on

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/17-BasicRegionNavigation

i want to Add **Authentication** to it :) , just simple **Login** and **Log out**...

i have `MainWindow` and `LoginView` (Both Two Windows)
my `Bootstraper.cs`

```
 class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        //return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();

            return Container.Resolve<LoginWindow>();
    }


    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {

        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();

    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        var catalog = (ModuleCatalog)ModuleCatalog;
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleInitializer));

    }
}
```

---

and my `LoginView` with Login Button:

and if there is another Method to deal with authentication in MVVM?

```
    private void Login_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    this.Close();

}
```

Comment: Please no screenshots of your code. CopyPaste the code as text

Comment: Im Sorry , i just want to show arrows for the lines that i have changed , thnak you.

Comment: Well, you can comment your code. No need for Bob Ross adventures ;o) - Please update your question

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it this way.  Your login dialog is not your Shell.  All you have to do is show the Login dialog before you call App.Current.MainWindow.Show.  If they successfully login, then show the shell, if they don't then do something else.  Don't over think it.

Comment: Thank you for Reply, i have Created that, and i want to implement Login/Logout ... before "App.Current.MainWindow.Show" i make LoginWindow object appears ... then from MainWindow i want to Back to Login ?

Comment: I want to have a `DelegatingHandler` that takes care of the login tokens. If the user isn't authenticated, it should request the user for credentials, authenticate them, and go on with the original HTTP request. How can I transfer a view + VM to the `DelegatingHandler` so that its displayed when needed? I want to implement something like `ICredentialsProvider` in my VM (or in the view if VM is not an option), so I can call the `ICredentialsProvider.GetCredentials` from within the `DelegatingHandler` pipeline to request credentials on demand?